# Filter a DataSet in terms of another DataSet in Scala flink

Tags: python, scala, numpy, apache-flink, entropy

I am trying to replicate this python code:

```
cond_entropy_x = np.array([entropy(x[y == v]) for v in uy])
```

Where `x` and `y` are vectors, and `uy` are the unique values on `y`, for example `0,1`.

In flink, I have:

```
val uy = y.distinct.collect
val condHx = for (i ← uy)
    yield entropy(x.filterWithBcVariable(y)((_, yy) ⇒ yy == i))
```

However, it seems `filterWithBcVariable` does not take every value on `y`, it only takes the first one.

I've also tried:

```
for (i ← values) yield y.join(x).where(a ⇒ a).equalTo(_ ⇒ i)
```

But I ran out of memory.

How could I filter `x` in terms of the values on `y`?

Something like `x.zip(y)` would do it, but it is not supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with one solution, may be is not the best, but at least its working.

Now, instead of passing `x` and `y` as separated `DataSets`, I am passing a `DataSet[LabeledVector]` with only a column:

```
val xy = input.map(lv ⇒ LabeledVector(lv.label, DenseVector(lv.vector(0))))
```

Then I pass `xy` to my function:

```
def conditionalEntropy(xy: DataSet[LabeledVector]): Double = {
    // Get the label
    val y = xy map (_.label)
    // Get probs for the label
    val p = probs(y).toArray.asBreeze
    // Get unique values in label
    val values = y.distinct.collect
    // Compute Conditional Entropy
    val condH = for (i ← values)
      yield entropy(xy.filter(_.label == i))
    p.dot(seq2Breeze(condH))
  }
```